# Filter query on a Solr spatial field is returning all documents with a non-null value

Tags: solr

Using Solr 7.7, I'm indexing simple rectangular polygons and I'm trying to filter them by an arbitrary bounding box, therefore I'm using the "range query syntax" trick that is documented on Solr's website.

Here is the definition of the field:

```
<fieldType name="my_geom"
   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
   spatialContextFactory="Geo3D"
   planetModel="WGS84"
   distanceUnits="kilometers"
   format="WKT"
   geo="true"
/>
<field name="*_geom" type="my_geom" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

And here is the query:

```
/select?fq=spatial_geom:[55.0260828,-115.5085624 TO 55.02646,-115.507337]&q=*:*
```

I'm expecting to only get results that fall within the defined bounding box but I'm actually getting ALL documents that have a non-null value in the "spatial_geom" field. Here is an example of a document that I'm not expecting to get (but I am):

```
{
    "spatial_geom":"POLYGON((-118.080201721669 54.5864541583249,-118.080201721669 54.5865258517606,-118.080078279314 54.5865258517606,-118.080078279314 54.5864541583249,-118.080201721669 54.5864541583249))",
    ...[other fields redacted]
}
```

**Edit 1:** Upgraded to Solr 8.0.0 and still encountering the same problem. Given that I'm getting *all* documents (with a non-null value) I suspect that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, I just can't see it.

**Edit 2:** For the sake of using simpler numbers to double check the data isn't bad, I loaded all of my documents with fake polygons using the following WKT `POLYGON((10 10,10 20,20 20,20 10,10 10))` and then queried using `?fq=spatial_geom:[30,30 TO 40,40]` and it still returned ALL documents!

Answer (score 1):

Geo3D requires that polygons adhere to the "right hand rule", and thus the exterior ring must be in counter-clockwise order and holes must be clockwise.  If you make this mistake then the meaning of the shape is inverted, and thus that little rectangle in Alberta Canada represents the inverse of that place.  Consequently most shapes will cover nearly the entire globe!  There is certainly a documentation issue needed in Solr to this effect.  Even I didn't know until I debugged this today!  It appears some of the GIS industry is migrating to this rule as well: http://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer/

Separately: I would be very curious to see how Geo3D compares to JTS after you get it working.  Additionally, you likely ought to use solr.RptWithGeometrySpatialField instead of solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType to get the full accuracy of the vector geometry instead of settling on a grid representation of shapes, otherwise your queries might get false-positives for just being close to an indexed shape.  Another thing to try is using prefixTree="s2" which is a not-yet-documented prefixTree that supposedly is much more efficient for Geo3D specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using JTS although I'm unsure why this was necessary and it significantly slowed down the data importing time.

Here is the new field type definition:

```
<fieldType name="my_geom"
  class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
  spatialContextFactory="JTS"
  autoIndex="true"
  distanceUnits="kilometers"
  format="WKT"
  geo="true"                                                                              
  />
```

I also downloaded the JTS jar, as per Solr's documentation.

However I still can't explain *why* using JTS is necessary considering the Solr documentation has led me to believe that I should be able to index polygons using Geo3D:

> Geo3D is the colloquial name of the Lucene spatial-3d module, included with Solr. It’s a computational geometry library implementing a variety of shapes (including polygons) on a sphere or WGS84 ellipsoid.

Using Geo3D gave me no errors during the import or the querying, it just didn't give me expected results. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

I also got it working with Solr's BBoxField type (and JTS). See field type definition:

```
<fieldType name="my_bbox"
  class="solr.BBoxField"
  spatialContextFactory="JTS"
  format="WKT"                                                                      
  geo="true"
  distanceUnits="kilometers"
  numberType="pdouble"
  />
```

It's still unclear to me why using `SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType` with `Geo3D` does not provide the correct results.

The data importing speed is significantly faster than using `SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType` with `JTS`.